# Perl: using regex in the same way that the hash

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to have the same output from regex that I already have with the hash below.
I am aware that my regex is quite ugly but I'm trying to improve it.

So the expect output from the regex is:

```
20191122181858|0292929|BVFEFZZ9C4|DIZJ4431573.ts|http://pdzr.rt.pl:8889
20191122181907|9836847|40EVFVRFB|DIZJ4432595.ts|http://pdzr.rt.pl:8889
```

**Here the code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

my (%hash); # initialization

if (<DATA>) { # if DATA exists
        print "here the regex values: \n";
        while (<DATA>) { # open the DATA
                chomp $_; # removes characters at the end of line
                my @tab = split(/,/, $_); # split lines
                my ($http, $ts, $macin, $caid) = (@tab[2, 3, 4, 5]);
                my $timestamp = strftime '%Y%m%d%H%M%S', localtime($ts/1000); # from unix epoch time to human read-able date
                my @value = split(/\//, $http); # split values of the http
                my ($url, $filename) = ("http://$value[2]", $value[6]); # value in order to have url and the name of the file
                if (! $hash{$timestamp."|".$caid."|".$macin."|".$filename."|".$url}) { # starting hash in order to avoid duplicates
                        $hash{$timestamp."|".$caid."|".$macin."|".$filename."|".$url} = $timestamp."|".$caid."|".$macin."|".$filename."|".$url;
                }
                my $regex = $_; # trying to have same output with a regex
                $regex =~ s/(?:[^\/]*\/)([^\\*]*\/)([^\.*]*)([^\,*]*)(\,)([^\,*]*)(\,)(.*)(.*)/http:\/$1|$2|$3|$4|$5|$6|$7/;
                print $regex, "\n";
        }
}

if (%hash) { # checking if hahs exists and contains values
        print "\nhere the hash values: \n";
        foreach (sort keys %hash) {
                print $_, "\n";
        }
}

__DATA__
"@timestamp",url,ts,macin,caid
"Nov 22, 2019 @ 17:19:07.571","http://pdzr.rt.pl:8889/qsdf/ZDF/vsLop/DIZJ4432595.ts/9836847.3018322401",1574443147021,40EVFVRFB,9836847
"Nov 22, 2019 @ 17:18:59.264","http://pdzr.rt.pl:8889/qsdf/ZDF/vsLop/DIZJ4431573.ts/0292929.5002731501",1574443138223,BVFEFZZ9C4,0292929
```

**Here the output:**

```
here the regex values:
http://pdzr.rt.pl:8889/qsdf/ZDF/vsLop/DIZJ4432595.ts/|9836847|.3018322401"|,|1574443147021|,|40EVFVRFB,9836847
http://pdzr.rt.pl:8889/qsdf/ZDF/vsLop/DIZJ4431573.ts/|0292929|.5002731501"|,|1574443138223|,|BVFEFZZ9C4,0292929

here the hash values:
20191122181858|0292929|BVFEFZZ9C4|DIZJ4431573.ts|http://pdzr.rt.pl:8889
20191122181907|9836847|40EVFVRFB|DIZJ4432595.ts|http://pdzr.rt.pl:8889
```

Comment: Regex has no output, matching or substitution have. Why do you want to switch to substitution?

Comment: yes, regex values come from the _DATA_. I want to switch to substitution in order to clean up the line, like all of them are the same format.

Comment: The _DATA_ are the source, I made the expected output already into the hash. So the hash is the reference. Then I would like to have the same reference with the substitution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex matches what you want and the substitute gives you the expected result, except the timestamp, you have to convert it like you did in the first part of your code:

```
^.+?(http://[^/]+).+/([^/]+?)/[^/]+?,(.+?),(.+?),(.+)
```

Replacement: `$3|$5|$4|$2|$1`

**Result:**

```
1574443147021|9836847|40EVFVRFB|DIZJ4432595.ts|http://pdzr.rt.pl:8889
1574443138223|0292929|BVFEFZZ9C4|DIZJ4431573.ts|http://pdzr.rt.pl:8889
```

[Regex demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/CXkSi5/3)

Here is the perl code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp $_;
    s~                          # SUBSTITUTE
        .+?                         # 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
        (http://[^/]+)              # group 1, URL until the first slash
        .+/                         # 1 or more any character but newline until a slash
        ([^/]+?)                    # group 2, 1 or more non slash
        /[^/]+?,                    # a slash, 1 or more non slash, a comma
        (.+?)                       # group 3, 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
        ,                           # a comma
        (.+?)                       # group 4, 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
        ,                           # a comma
        (.+)                        # group 5, 1 or more any character but newline
    ~                           # WITH
        strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S',    # convert time
        localtime($3/1000))
        .                           # CONCAT WITH
        "|$5|$4|$2|$1"              # groups 5, 4, 2, 1 joined with pipes
    ~ex;                            # 
    print $_, "\n";
}

__DATA__
"@timestamp",url,ts,macin,caid
"Nov 22, 2019 @ 17:19:07.571","http://pdzr.rt.pl:8889/qsdf/ZDF/vsLop/DIZJ4432595.ts/9836847.3018322401",1574443147021,40EVFVRFB,9836847
"Nov 22, 2019 @ 17:18:59.264","http://pdzr.rt.pl:8889/qsdf/ZDF/vsLop/DIZJ4431573.ts/0292929.5002731501",1574443138223,BVFEFZZ9C4,0292929
```

**Output:**

```
"@timestamp",url,ts,macin,caid
20191122181907|9836847|40EVFVRFB|DIZJ4432595.ts|http://pdzr.rt.pl:8889
20191122181858|0292929|BVFEFZZ9C4|DIZJ4431573.ts|http://pdzr.rt.pl:8889
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are many ways to achieve same result. Bellow is my *extended* version which not just *shuffle* around fields but separate them into hash and does some manipulation on them [timestamp].

From the original post it is not clear if *timestamp* should be taken from the data or generated at run time -- I took *timestamp* from data.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature qw(say);

use Data::Dumper;

my $debug = 0;

my %row;
my %url;
my @fields  = qw( timestamp url ts macin caid );
my @address = qw( proto dn port dir id );

while( <DATA> ) {
    next if /timestamp/;

    print if $debug;

    chomp;
    s/,//;
    s/"//g;

    @row{@fields} = split ',';

    print Dumper(\%row) if $debug;

    @url{@address} = ( $row{url} =~ m#(\w+)://(.+):(\d+)/(.+)/(.+)# );

    $url{id}    =~ s/\.\d+//;
    $url{dir}   =~ /(\w+\.ts)/;
    $url{ts}    = $1;

    print Dumper(\%url) if $debug;

    say join('|', (
            timestamp($row{timestamp}),
            $url{id},
            $row{macin},
            $url{ts},
            "$url{proto}://$url{dn}:$url{port}"
            ));

}

sub timestamp {
    my $input = shift;

    my %data;
    my $result;

    my %months = ( Jan => 1, Feb => 2, Mar => 3, Apr => 4,
                   May => 5, Jun => 6, Jul => 7, Aug => 8,
                   Sep => 9, Oct => 10, Nov => 11, Dec => 12
                 );

    my @fields = qw( month day year hour min sec msec ); 

    @data{@fields} = /(\w+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+@\s+(\d+):(\d+):(\d+).(\d+)/;

    print Dumper(\%data) if $debug;

    $result = sprintf "%4d%02d%02d%02d%02d",
                    $data{year},
                    $months{$data{month}},
                    $data{hour},
                    $data{min},
                    $data{sec};

    return $result;
}

__DATA__
"@timestamp",url,ts,macin,caid
"Nov 22, 2019 @ 17:19:07.571","http://pdzr.rt.pl:8889/qsdf/ZDF/vsLop/DIZJ4432595.ts/9836847.3018322401",1574443147021,40EVFVRFB,9836847
"Nov 22, 2019 @ 17:18:59.264","http://pdzr.rt.pl:8889/qsdf/ZDF/vsLop/DIZJ4431573.ts/0292929.5002731501",1574443138223,BVFEFZZ9C4,0292929
```

The output of the result

```
201911171907|9836847|40EVFVRFB|DIZJ4432595.ts|http://pdzr.rt.pl:8889
201911171859|0292929|BVFEFZZ9C4|DIZJ4431573.ts|http://pdzr.rt.pl:8889
```